# Python Selenium: Unable to access DOM with PhantomJS Driver

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

I am trying to access HTML of a page via Selenium. When access via Firefox driver then accessed fine but not with PhantomJS and it does not load page at all. The code is given below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

try:
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='/Setups/phantomjs-1.9.8-macosx/bin/phantomjs')
    driver.maximize_window()
    # driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get('https://www.propertyshark.com/mason/')
    element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'search_token'))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(element_present)
    print(driver.page_source)

except Exception as ex:
    print(str(ex))
finally:
    driver.save_screenshot('screen.png')
    driver.quit()
```

In exception it leaves message `Message:` that's it.

Ideally I wanted to stick with Python `requests` but that's not working due to JS based site.

Comment: I am not sure what your problem is, but your code, with a phantomJS 2.1.1 and Python 3.6 (along with Selenium 3.7) in a Ubtuntu 16.04 (64 bit) ran without any problem and printed out a hell lot of HTML on the screen. Are you sure you are using the latest version of phantomJS? Maybe updating your version will solve this issue.

Comment: seems phantomjs version problem

Comment: Did it solve after updating Phantomjs?

Comment: BTW, I just came across [this](https://github.com/tryolabs/requestium) Maybe something you can look into as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Update your version of Phantom JS first. Hopefully it will fix the issue.